# How to use the fetch() API in JavaScript Strict Mode?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, strict

If I put `"use strict";` at the top of my file, the compiler will throw an error saying that `'fetch' is not defined` (alongside `document.` or `event.` calls, but those I kind of know how to circumvent).

Comment: What compiler? Are you using Babel/TypeScript/ESLint? If so, provide your configuration file and some of your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: are you in a node environment? if so fetch isn't native.

Comment: @MadameTuxstdout: That link is to the main JSFiddle page, and not to your code.  If you choose "save", your URL should change to a shareable page.  But note that the [inline snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753) are handier for HTML, CSS, and JS in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my above comment if you are trying to use fetch in node you will need to use a library, but in a browser environment I can't duplicate your issue (see below)

```js
'use strict';

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(res => (res.ok) ? res.json() : new Error('something went wrong'))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was playing with my code in a browser environment, so I assumed that the same behavior will occur on the production server. I was wrong.